# unbound module Event error when compiling Ocaml game

Tags: module, compiler-errors, ocaml

Am new to Ocaml and i was trying to compile the game mltetris from http://lambda-diode.com/software/ocaml/. I am using windows 7 with ocaml version 4.00.0 however when i try to compile using the command below. I get this error

```
C:\Users\WASSWA SAM\ocaml stuff\mltetris>ocamlc -pp camlp4o -o tetris.exe human.
ml game.ml play.ml tetris.ml tetris.mli
File "play.ml", line 21, characters 16-26:
Error: Unbound module Event
```

Isn't the Event Module supposed to be part of the standard distribution. I checked the libraries using this command

```
C:\Users\WASSWA SAM\ocaml stuff\mltetris>ocamlfind list
bigarray            (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4              (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.exceptiontracer (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.extend       (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.foldgenerator (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.fulllib      (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.gramlib      (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.lib          (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.listcomprehension (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.locationstripper (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.macro        (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.mapgenerator (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.metagenerator (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.profiler     (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.quotations   (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.quotations.o (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.quotations.r (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.tracer       (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
compiler-libs       (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
compiler-libs.bytecomp (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
compiler-libs.common (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
compiler-libs.optcomp (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
compiler-libs.toplevel (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
dbm                 (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
dynlink             (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
findlib             (version: 1.3.3)
graphics            (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
labltk              (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
num                 (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
num-top             (version: 1.3.3)
num.core            (version: [internal])
ocamlbuild          (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
stdlib              (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
str                 (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
threads             (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
threads.posix       (version: [internal])
unix                (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
```

What's missing I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Event` is part of the standard library.

On my machine, the following sequence of commands is working:

```
ocamlopt -thread  -c human.ml
ocamlopt -thread  -c game.ml
ocamlopt -thread  -c tetris.ml
ocamlopt -thread  -c play.ml
ocamlopt -thread  unix.cmxa threads.cmxa graphics.cmxa human.cmx game.cmx tetris.cmx play.cmx   -o tetris.opt
```

---

Instead of manually compiling every file, which may work in this case, a more long term approach is to use the provided Makefile, by just issuing the command

```
make
```

(The above commands are actually what `make` runs).
It seems you're under Windows, in which case an option is to install Cygwin, wich provides a version of `make`. Cygwin is a whole chapter in itself, read about it before you start.

Comment: Am now getting an error when i try your code.                   'i686-w64-mingw32-as' is not recognized as an internal or     external command,
operable program or batch file.
File "human.ml", line 1:
Error: Assembler error, input left in file C:\Users\WASSWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
camlasmcb1c14.s

Comment: Let's try at first to stay close to your previous attempt. I would try to just add the required option and compiled modules to the command that was almost working: try `ocamlc -custom -thread -pp camlp4o -o tetris.exe unix.cma threads.cma graphics.cma human.ml game.ml tetris.mli tetris.ml play.ml` (BTW, why did you add `-pp camlp4o `?).

Answer (score 1):

The events module appears to be part of the threads facility.  The manual says this:

> Programs that use system threads must be linked as follows:

```
   ocamlc -thread other options unix.cma threads.cma other files  
   ocamlopt -thread other options unix.cmxa threads.cmxa other files
```